# Javascript inside svg not working on phantomJs

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs

I have an svg file with javascript inside for handling click events.
It works fine in browsers, but it is not working with phantomJS.

If I put the script outside the `<svg></svg>` it works but I want to let the script inside the svg block

**UPDATE**

**WORKING**

```
<body>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 550">
    <svg id="secondSVG" width="700px" height="550px"> 
      <rect id="arect" height="250" width="250" x="100" y="0"</rect>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    console.log("It is working");}
    document.getElementById('arect').setAttribute('fill', #000000);
  </script>
</body>
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
<body>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 550">
    <svg id="secondSVG" width="700px" height="550px"> 
      <rect id="arect" height="250" width="250" x="100" y="0"</rect>
      <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        window.onload = function() {
        console.log("It is working");}
        document.getElementById('arect').setAttribute('fill', #000000);
      ]]></script>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Better if you show us the code.

Comment: What happens if you lose the `<![CDATA[` `]]>` bits and the script type attribute?

Comment: I obtain the same result